# Can I use drag and drop of html5 on mobile devices with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, drag-and-drop

I need a drag and drop to mobile devices using phonegap. I tried with jquery mobile and jquery ui + jquery touch punch but html5 is better for me. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Francisco

//EDIT

Here is a draggable image :

```
<a href="" name="cebra" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)" > 
<img src="Imagenes/cebra.png" alt="cebra" width="150" height="100" id=""      style="background-color: #FFFFFF; display: block;" ; /> 
</a>
```

and the function of javascript

```
function dragUser(user, event) { 
     event.dataTransfer.setData('User', user.id); 
 }
```

I need to know if I can make a draggable image to android with the property draggable = "True" and phonegap. I can make this with jquery ui + jquery ui touch punch but could be better with html5 for my application.

Comment: Hi may possibly a duplicate of this below thread check out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942784/html5-drag-and-drop-mobile

Comment: thanks for answer. I saw the post, but it's possible without jquery?

Comment: I believe to perform an interactivity u need javascript...so using jquery gives u no harm....

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried?

Answer (score 4):

Hi Fransisco,
              Drag and drop feature can be added by using jQuery UI, and we have implemented this in web, android and iOS applications(Using phonegap also). So go ahead with this and please refer the following links,

- http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
- http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: Thanks you, i used that, but the interaction isn't natural in android. Sorry, I dont know how end to the question.