# Drag and Drop functionality in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, drag-and-drop

How is the drag and drop functionality implemented in PhoneGap?

I tried using the Native HTML5's new drag and drop feature, but that doesn't works.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975221/can-i-use-drag-and-drop-of-html5-on-mobile-devices-with-phonegap/20517992#20517992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQueryUI as given here in these two documentations:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: Working on phone gap desktop app (which opens in browser), but not working in android device.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop feature can be added by using jQuery UI, and we have implemented this in web, android and iOS applications(Using phonegap also). So go ahead with this and please refer the following links,

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

You need code which implement touch events such as: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch