# Drag and Drop Cordova Image

Tags: image, cordova, plugins, drag-and-drop

First of all, I'm using cordova.

I wanna do an application which get a picture and shows it at the screen (it's done!). Now, I need to pick some other little images, drag and drop them on the original picture, save the modifications and send to a server...

How can I do the drag and drop AND save the big image after dropped little images? (if possible, using plugins)

I saw this, but how can I save as a new image?
[Drag and Drop functionality in PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518284/drag-and-drop-functionality-in-phonegap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I did this:

---

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- meta -->
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <!-- css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/camera.css">
        <!-- js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/camera.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/compartilhamento.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <!--script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <!-- js drag and drop -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/add-aderecos.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/salva-canvas.js"></script>

    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="" id="botoes">
            <p><a href="menu.html">Voltar</a></p>
            <p><input type="button" onClick="tiraFoto()" value="Acessar Câmera"></p>
        </div>
        <!--Aqui estao os objetos disponibilizados para drag-->
        <div id="objetos" style="display: none;">
            <p>Clique na imagem que desejar adicionar à sua foto!</p>
            <img src="img/nariz.png" id="add-nariz"></img>
            <hr/>
        </div>

        <!--Pega as dimensoes da foto vinda da camera/galeria e posteriormente é cópia do canvas, para que possa ser compartilhado via social-x-sharing plugin-->
        <img id="pegaDim" src="" style="display: none;"></img>

        <!--aqui está a foto tirada, com redimensionamento via CSS. Aqui acontece a edicao da imagem-->
        <div id="box-foto">
            <img src="" id="imagemCamera" style="display: none;"></img>
        </div>

        <!--pra cá será copiada a imagem editada-->
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>

        <!--botoes-->
        <div id="compartilhamento" style="display: none;">
            <p><input type="button" value="Salvar Mudanças" id="salvaImagem"/></p>
            <p><input type="button" onclick="imagemTeste('pegaDim');" value="Compartilhar Imagem" /></p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

### camera.js

```
function tiraFoto() {

    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
        {
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
        }
    );
}

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    //pega DOM
    var compartilha = document.getElementById('compartilhamento');
    var botoes = document.getElementById('botoes');
    var pegaDim = document.getElementById('pegaDim');
    var image = document.getElementById('imagemCamera');
    var objetos = document.getElementById('objetos');

    //aparece depois da foto
    objetos.style.display = 'block';
    pegaDim.src = imageData;
    image.src = imageData;
    image.style.display = 'block';
    compartilha.style.display = 'block';
    botoes.style.display = 'none';

}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Erro: ' + message);
}
```

---

### add-aderecos.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-nariz', function(){
    var a = $('#add-nariz');
    var src = a.attr('src');
    var elem = $('<img class="objetos" src="' + src + '" width="30px" height="30px" style="positon: relative;" />');
    $('#box-foto').append(elem);
    elem.draggable();
});
```

---

### salva-canvas.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#salvaImagem', function(){

  //pega dimensoes originais da foto da camera/galeria
  var dimensoesOriginais = document.getElementById('pegaDim');
  var larguraOriginal = dimensoesOriginais.width;
  var alturaOriginal = dimensoesOriginais.height;

  //pega a imagem que aparece na tela e o canvas
  var m = $('#imagemCamera');
  var totX = parseInt(m.css('width'));
  var totY = parseInt(m.css('height'));
  var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  c.width = totX;
  c.height = totY;
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  //alert(totX + '\n' + totY);

  var base = m[0];
  //drawImage(imagem,comecaCorteX,comecaCorteY,paraCorteX,paraCorteY,X,Y,Largura,Altura)
  ctx.drawImage(base,0,0,larguraOriginal,alturaOriginal,0,0,totX,totY);

  var posicoes = [];
  $(".objetos").each(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    x = parseInt(img.css("left"))+totX;
    y = parseInt(img.css("top"))+totY;
    altura = parseInt(img.css("width"));
    largura = parseInt(img.css("height"));
    posicoes.push([ 
     x,
     y,
     largura,
     altura,
    ]);
  });
  //alert( JSON.stringify(posicoes));
  //pega a imagem do nariz -- palheativo
  var copiasNariz = $('#add-nariz')[0];
  //loop pra canvas
  var j;
  var numAderecos = posicoes.length;
  for(j = 0; j < numAderecos; j++){
    //drawImage(imagem,comecaCorteX,comecaCorteY,paraCorteX,paraCorteY,X,Y,Largura,Altura)
    ctx.drawImage(copiasNariz,posicoes[j][0]-156+(j*posicoes[j][2]),posicoes[j][1],posicoes[j][2],posicoes[j][3]);
    alert('posicao inicial: ' + posicoes[j][0] + '\n\nposicao final: ' + posicoes[j][0]-156+(j*posicoes[j][2]) + '\n\nvariacao de :' + (-156+(j*posicoes[j][2])));
  }

  //Esconde a foto original e mostra o canvas
  var some = document.getElementById('box-foto');
  c.style.display = "block";
  some.style.display = "none";
  //esconde os objetos arrastaveis
  $('#objetos')[0].style.display = "none";
  //faz uma copia do canvas como src de uma tag img -- vai pro pegaDim
  var finalImageToShare = new Image();
  var srcFinal = finalImageToShare.src;
  srcFinal = c.toDataURL();
  dimensoesOriginais.src = srcFinal;
});
```

---

### compartilhamento.js

```
function imagemTeste(idTag) {
    var tag = document.getElementById(idTag);
    var img = tag.src;
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Imagem compartilhada via aplicativo X.', 'Assunto (caso envie por email)', img, null);
}
```

I really sorry for the portuguese ids, classes and the names of variables or functions, but I'm afraid when I change to english forgot something and this stops working. So I copied the code as it is in my real project.

I believe my code is "ugly" and longer than necessary, but I'm not so good with javaScript yet.